# Meaning of 농담이 심하다

Tags: vocabulary

This expression appeared on my vocabulary textbook as a collocation of the word "joke" 농담(弄談).
What I could not understand is the exact meaning of [심하다](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%8B%AC%ED%95%98%EB%8B%A4)(甚하다) in this collocation. Does is it mean a "terrible joke", "great joke" or maybe "cruel joke" as in a joke that went too far? What is the exact connotation of 농담이 심하다? Could someone provide some usage examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 농담이 심하다 when **you think** that **a joke** has been **carried too far**. It does *not* matter whether it is really a joke. The adjective 심하다 has a negative connotation because it is used when something exceeds a reasonable/acceptable level. I will give you some dialogues below.

**Dialogue 1** (ㄱ is telling the truth.)

> ㄱ: **사실 네가 내 아들이야.** (In fact, you are my son.)
>
> ㄴ: 에이, 농담이 심하시네요.
>
> ㄱ: 내가 지금 농담하는 줄 아나?
>
> ㄴ: 농담이 아니에요?
>
> ㄱ: 그래, 농담 아니야. 네가 내 아들이 아니라면 내가 왜 너 같은 애하고 대화하겠니?

**Dialogue 2** (ㄷ is telling a sick joke.)

> ㄷ: **나, 얼마 못 산대.** (I was told that I am not going to live much longer.)
>
> ㄹ: 뭐? 정말이야? 무슨 불치병이라도 걸렸어?
>
> ㄷ: **응, 병 걸렸어. 너 없이는 못 사는 병.** (Yes, I caught a disease. The "I can't live without you" disease.)
>
> ㄹ: 야, 농담이 너무 심하잖아. 네가 얼마 못 산대서 내가 속으로 얼마나 놀란 줄 알아?

**Dialogue 3** (ㅁ is telling a joke that could be taken as sexual harassment.)

> ㅁ: 옆 부서 사람이랑 단둘이 출장 가니?
>
> ㅂ: 어. 내일 하루 갔다 와.
>
> ㅁ: 그렇구나. 잘 다녀와. **그 사람이랑 좋은 시간도 보내고.** (Have a good time with her / him, too.)
>
> ㅂ: 내가 너냐? 농담도 심하다.

There are several synonyms for 심하다: 과하다, 지나치다, 너무하다, etc. For 농담이 심하다, you can use 과하다 or 지나치다 instead of 심하다, but 농담이 너무하다 sounds too awkward.

Answer (score 3):

심하다 used mainly in negative situations. So 농담이 심하다 means that the joke is too harsh or excessive. It can also be used in the following sentences: 말이 심하다(speaking too harsh), 장난이 심하다(prank too much). 과하다, 과도하다, 지나치다 can be used as synonym.

Comment: +1 for a simple explanation.